# Create a draft mail using google gmail API with asp.net WebForms (without libraries)

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, http-post, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Gmail API to create and send an email draft.
I've looked the documentation and some forum threads trying to solve this problem over a week, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's the last modified code that I am using to do this job:

```
string URL = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/" + usrEmail + "/drafts?access_token=" + hdfToken.Value;
        string mBody = "From: " + txbMail.Text + "\nTo: " + txbDest.Text + "\nSubject: " + txbAssunto.Text + "\n\r\n" + txbMsg.Text + "";
        string payload = "{\"message\": {\"raw\": \"" + Base64Encode(mBody) + "\"}}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.Default, "message/rfc822");

            var response = client.PostAsync($"" + URL, content).Result;
            string resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(resultContent);
            string draftID = jsonObject["id"].ToString();
            hdfID.Value = draftID;
            lblID.Text = "#ID: |" + draftID + "|<br>";
            //return resultContent;
        }
```

And here is the method to encode the content sent:

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace("=", "");
    }
```

I am able to create the draft, but it always is created empty. But if I copy the content sent (string named "payload") and put it in the Google test page (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create) the draft is created correctly -> with sender e-mail address, E-mail subject, e-mail body and receiver e-mail address I've sent.
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here, so I came here asking for your help.

This code is executed in and ASP.NET C# webforms page. Any Ideas?

***updated content below:
I've created a simple form to test the API and did the form submit. Let's see the data:
[Simple Form created to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2fk2.jpg)

On my draft folder, this is the result:
[Empty Draft Message created by my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo5FX.jpg)

An empty draft...
If I copy the content sent and paste it on the test form:
[Google Test API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCEfD.jpg)

The draft is created with the fields filled in correctly:
[Draft Message with filled fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e9Ez.jpg)

And it's driving me crazy lol.

Comment: @mason thank you for your words. i will update my question with the correct description.

Comment: Have you compared the `Base64Encode()` function result with the one you use on the Try this API? Have you checked if there is something different by logging before the message is sent?

Comment: Hi Kessy. Yes, i did. I will update the post with some prins of the tests i did. If i copy the result and paste it on the test page, my draft is created with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem.
I was using a wrong url to post my data.
The correct url to do this is:
[https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/drafts](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/drafts)